# Vulkan Raytracing: Distances to hitted triangle aren't sorted

Tags: c, glsl, vulkan

I have some issue with the raytracing-shaders, I can't get fixed. I'm using vulkan and glsl.
The distances to the primitives aren't sorted. Which means, the ray seems to hit a tringle first which is further away than another. Is that a normal behavior or did i do something wrong?
I validate this data with matlab, which means, for every pixel in my image I return the primitives and the distances to do futher calculation (max 40). But in the result data, (you can see it below) the distances are not sorted and that causes big calculationtime to reorder it.

Here you can see the any-hit-shader:

```
#version 460
#extension GL_NV_ray_tracing : require
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : enable

layout(binding = 4, set = 0) buffer primitiveProperties
{
    float ids[];    
} primitives;


layout(binding = 6, set = 0) buffer distanceProperties
{
    float values[]; 
} distances;

struct RayPayload {
    uint outputId;
    uint hitCounter;    
};

layout(location = 0) rayPayloadInNV RayPayload rayPayload;
hitAttributeNV vec3 attribs;

void main()
{   

    uint outputIdCurrentTriangle = rayPayload.outputId + rayPayload.hitCounter++;
  primitives.ids[outputIdCurrentTriangle] = gl_PrimitiveID + 1;  
  distances.values[outputIdCurrentTriangle] = gl_HitTNV;  
  ignoreIntersectionNV();

}
```

And the ray is generated normally:

```
traceNV(topLevelAS, rayFlags, cullMask, 0, 0, 0, origin.xyz, tmin, direction.xyz, tmax, 0);
```

But the result looks like:
[distances of a pixel][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCDhl.png

In form of data:
0.83021832
0.83021832
0.84927511
0.84927511
0.94443458
0.94443458
0.94811541
0.94811541
1.0063932
1.0063932
0.97728723
0.97728723
0.98426312
0.98426312

And maybe there are more mistakes in it.
So my question again: is it normal that this happens?

Thank you for every help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is perfectly normal and expected behavior.

Your any-hit-shader is by design intended to be invoked as the GPU traverses the acceleration structure (which happens in arbitrary order, whatever fits the data layout best). You are then (usually) only supposed to call one of `ignoreIntersectionNV()` or `reportIntersectionNV()`, depending on whether it's a *possible* hit or not. You are *not* expected to count it as a valid hit yet.

You don't know anything about order until the closest hit shader has been invoked. You can record any-hits encountered on the way, but then you will need to discard ones outside the range later on, and order the rest as required.

The only exception where you can already do something meaningful in the any-hit-shader is in case of visibility tests against infinity (skybox, infinite distance light sources). In that case, *any* hit may be accepted and you may call `terminateRayNV()` right away.

---

Naive use of raytracing via Nvidias Vulkan extension is not suitable for solving order related problems.

For that, you must either launch rays in an iterative fashion (filter in any-hit or even VK_GEOMETRY_OPAQUE_BIT, re-launch in closest-hit) or construct a good old D-buffer based on potential hits you have recorded from any-hit invocations.

If you require ordered hits, and your geometry isn't too complex, then you may rather have a look at signed-distance-fields, if suitable for your application. They provide stable order during traversal.

Comment: Hi, 
wow, thank you for the great and fast answer. It is not realy a problem to do order it after all, but I want to be sure about that. So, thank you very much!